# The package react@15.6.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am not sure why I am getting this error. This is a project that my team is working on and I tried to just install some packages and every time I do I get these errors in the command line:

[image]

I have tried to update, remove, uninstall, manually remove and reinstall and nothing seems to work.

Comment: does your project have `package-lock.json` ?.

Comment: Yes! It does do you need that?

Comment: No. So i think it is happening coz of version mismatch of some of the packages. You should find out what version of `npm` your teammates are using and use the same version. Then remove your `node_modules` folder and then try to run `npm install`

Comment: Okay I will try to do that! should I remove both lock and normal package.json?

Comment: No. You should not touch package.json or package-lock.json. Just remove your `node_modules` folder and try to run npm install.

Comment: That did not fix it.

Comment: have you updated your npm and node to match your teammate version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155944/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-panther).